# Understanding of a class-based component to rewrite into functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am currently trying to rewrite a [class-based component](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react/blob/master/src/OTPublisher.js) into a functional component. In the link, you can find one specific section:

```
this.publisherId = uuid();
const { publisherId } = this;

this.errorHandler = once((err) => {
    if (publisherId !== this.publisherId) {
    // Either this publisher has been recreated or the
    // component unmounted so don't invoke any callbacks
    return;
    }
    if (typeof this.props.onError === 'function') {
    this.props.onError(err);
    }
});

const publisher = OT.initPublisher(container, properties, (err) => {
    if (publisherId !== this.publisherId) {
    // Either this publisher has been recreated or the
    // component unmounted so don't invoke any callbacks
    return;
    }
```

The function `createPublisher()` first defines: `this.publisherId = uuid();` and afterwards `const { publisherId } = this;`. Then it will be checked in different parts of the code `if (publisherId !== this.publisherId)`. I wonder, how would you write that check for a functional-based component since `this` is not available there?

Comment: In function components, you can declare variables on base level, so it's fine to define it outside of any method. I see you seem to use this in other places as well as a state variable; you could use the `useState` hook to create the variable, this allow you to steer it accordingly as you do now.

Comment: Hi gqstav, you mean that I basically write `publisherId = uuid();` and in the next line I will change `const { publisherId } = this;` to setUUID(publisherId). And then I check `if (publisherId !== UUID) `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With functional components you can use a `ref` to preserve the value of a variable between renders.

```
// Create an empty publisherId
const publisherIdRef = useRef();

// Assign it
publisherIdRef.current = uuid();

// Test it
if (publisherIdRef.current !== publisherId) ...
```

Comment: With `!== publisherId` you meant `!== publisherIdRef`, correct?

Comment: No, my code is correct, the equivalent of your former `this.publisherId` is now `publisherIdRef.current`